# Discrepancy between google analytics transactions and Odoo number of orders

Tags: google-analytics, odoo, e-commerce, enhanced-ecommerce

I have added google analytics tag to my client's website (They are using Odoo platform) through a Google Tag Manager Container. I also (Along with their backend developers) implemented the data layer to activate the enhanced e-commerce feature. it used to work perfectly, however, about 2 months ago we started to see a discrepancy between GA transactions and Odoo Sales orders. In March, GA reported 35 transactions, while Odoo reported 128 for the same time period (from 1-3-2021 to 21-3-2021).

**The following screenshots show all the tags on GTM:**

[Google Tag Manager Tags 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPCgP.png)

[Google Tag Manager Tags 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf9bB.png)

**The following screenshot shows the data layer implementation**

[E-Commerce Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEJa8.png)

**The following screenshots show the purchase tag configuration**

[Google Analytics - Purchase Tag 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxo8P.png) 
[Google Analytics - Purchase Tag 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVPyF.png) 
[Google Analytics - Purchase Tag - Trigger Group Configuratin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq7Bv.png) 
[Google Analytics - Purchase Tag - Confirmation Page Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OPOC.png)

I have exhausted all the possible reasons for such behavior , and I can't seem to find an explanation & a solution for this discrepancy. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you implemented a new cookiebar in the last 2 months?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.